# Using Cheesecloth for Pancetta

Tags: drying, charcuterie, pancetta

I am making pancetta for the first time and I've just taken it out of the cure to dry.  I have rolled it and am ready to hang it.  Before I hang it, what are the pros and cons of wrapping it in cheesecloth while it dries?  The recipe I am using says to cover it in cheesecloth when laying flat to dry, but nothing about wrapping it in cheesecloth to hang it.

Answer (score 1):

I've made pancetta many times.  When rolling, I just tie with a string. Traditionally, it is just tied off.  Personally, I prefer the results when I just hang it without rolling...poke a hole, loop a string, hang...but that is just personal preference.  The only downside I can see to the cheese cloth, is that it might slightly slow the drying process.  Other than that, as long as you are working clean, I can't see a problem with it, but I am not sure it really helps you in any significant way.  Perhaps you could get a tighter roll with a sheet of cheesecloth?

Answer (score 0):

Cheese cloth would actually be great as it will inhibit some bugs getting to the meat while still being porous enough as to not let the meat sweat.

If your hanging in the summer it is a good thing to cover the meat with something. You just need a substance that lets the meat breath. If it is just a regular bag the meat can sweat and this could open the door for spoilage bacteria to enter.